# Running a python script on files in multiple directories, on files that need to be extracted

Tags: python, bash

I have a file architecture like this:

```
A/folder1/file.tar.gz
B/folder2/file.tar.gz
```

I have a python script that I want to run on these files

Is there any way I can extract every file and then run my script, using bash or something in python?

Comment: I cannot see the problem in extracting the files. Which is the difficulty? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to extract each file in one command to the same directory it is in, but I am also worried that there will not be enough space - compressed these files are 80gb, so ideally I'd want to extract, run the python script, and then delete the uncompressed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using find you can get your list of files and process them one by one:

```
for TGZ in $(find . -name "file.tar.gz")
do
    WD=$(dirname $TGZ)
    cd $WD
    tar xzf file.tar.gz
    <your python script>
    rm *.faa
    cd -
done
```

That would be a direct translation of your words: uncompress the files in the same folder where they are, process them and remove the data. I'm assuming that the extracted files are only *.faa files. There is also quite a lot of directory movement due to your script only working with the filed in the current folder.

Personally, I would feel safer by using a sligtly different approach:

```
for TGZ in $(find . -name "file.tar.gz")
do
    mkdir -p work
    cd work
    tar xzf $TGZ
    <your python script>
    cd ..
    rm -rf work
done
```

There is also folder movement, but you always move to the same place and you do a complete cleanup, in case there are other things besides *.faa files.

Regarding your python script... did you though of using a dictionary instead of a bunch of single-letter vars?

```
base = dict()
base['A'] = 0
base['A'] += 1
```

That would reduce your code size quite a lot and make it more readable.

Comment: Would this work with a wildcard? e.g `for TGZ in $(find . -name "*.tar.gz")`? My files aren't actually called file, they all have different names

Comment: Yes, it will work with wildcards as long as you keep the wilcard inside quotes, as is already written.

Answer (score 0):

You might having a master folder which has all the folders which contain your tar.gz files.
This will extract all files in one cammand
Now lets say 'data' is your root folder which has all the subfolders which further contain your tar.gz files.

now

```
> for root,dirs,files in os.walk('path to data folder'):
>         for name in files:   
>             if(name.endswith('.gz'):
>                 #Run your script here
```